# If I echo a string with output-buffering and get the buffer, will I always get back the original string?

Tags: php, echo, output-buffering

More specifically, can the block of code

```
ob_start(); 
echo $astring; 
$astring = ob_get_clean();
```

change the value of $astring ? In other words, I want to know how reliable is the combination of echo, output-buffering and getting the buffer. Of course, I have tested it. With simple strings, in my tests, the string stays the same. I want to know if I can rely on this being always the case. Is there any possible exception? What could make a difference is the occurrence of special escape characters in the string, things like that.

Comment: The simple answer is TRY IT AND SEE.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, of course, I did that and it is the same in my tests, but this does not mean there are no other circumstances where it will be different.

Comment: Anyway, originally, I had a more complex question about a more complex setting and I reduced it to this simpler one. I could reduce it to even a simpler one. Does `ob_start(); echo $astring; $astring = ob_get_clean();` can change the value of $astring ? I think the answer is no. If I test with a simple string, it will not change the string.  Is that true in all circumstances? I will edit the question. It is a simple one, but I want an authoritative answer.

Comment: If you want an authoritative answer then you have to ask on a different site. At [`php.net`](http://news.php.net/php.general), maybe. Or take a look at the `PHP`s source code, it is on [`github`](https://github.com/php/php-src/). Or read the PHP manual pages about [`echo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) and [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) and draw your own conclusion.

Comment: There are exceptions, of course. It depends of what you do between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` and of other factors (I'll try to build a script to show this); an [`ob_clean()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php) inserted before `ob_get_clean()` will clean the output buffer and let `ob_get_clean()` without any content to return (it will return the empty string `''`).

Comment: @axiac, sure, I can always try to answer the question myself.  I think the idea of asking is to see if someone has already some reference about this or maybe he has tested this in many different contexts and he can share his experience. About SO not being the right place, I did not know that. Oups, you added a comment in between.

Comment: @axiac, there is no ob_clean in between in the question. I really refer to this specific block of code, the three lines. So, what could make a difference is the occurrence of special escape characters in the string, things like that.

Comment: Asking on SO is ok. You said you want an **authoritative** answer. I think only the source code or the guys that wrote it can give you an authoritative answer. We can, as you said, help you with things we encounter in the past but it could be only luck if we always got the expected result.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need this trick?

Comment: I had a file that was included in another file and this other file was output-buffered.  The string associated with the first file was a sub-string of this buffered string. Now, I am getting the sub-string first (through a separate output-buffering) and then echo it in the other file, because I need the variables that are defined in the original file in between. Plenty of things can happen in between, but at the least I want to know that the extra echo in the buffer will not by itself be the problem.  So, I reduced the question to whether or not echoing in the buffer is a reliable channel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68814/discussion-between-axiac-and-dominic108).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a paste and cut of a comment made by axiac:  The output buffer is nothing else than a hidden string variable. It is as reliable as any other string variable to hold any amount of text, limited by the memory_limit php.ini configuration (minus other data your script creates and the internal PHP structures for memory management) and the amount of memory available on the computer (which is virtually unlimited due to paging).

Comment: It might seem like obvious, but for me it was not. After all, why an "output buffer" is used to manipulate a string before we actually output it.  In my view, before this answer, if it is an output buffer, then it is not to be   manipulated and, if you do retrieve it for manipulation, the result could be unpredictable.   In other words, I felt that ob_start() etc. were tools that we should not use, except in special cases. Perhaps that this will help others that I have the same incorrect understanding of ob_start(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: this answer does not actually address the OP's issue. We continued the discussion in the chat (see the comments on the question) and it seems the OP was satisfied with the explanation I gave there and clarified themselves their bewilderment.

---

As I promised in the comment, this is a piece of code that will make your code fail. It is artificially created for this discussion.

However, when you work on a big project, the error handler can be installed somewhere in a deeply included file (or by the framework), the effect of `unset($astring);` could be achieved by a typo or by simply forgetting to store a value into the variable and the final result comes in unexpected.

```
// Install an error handler that will output the error messages it gets
set_error_handler(
    function($errno, $errstr) {
        echo('The error #'.$errno.' happened. The message is: '.$errstr);
        return FALSE;
    },
    E_NOTICE
);

// Ensure the notices won't show to the surface (they will pollute the 
// script's output on screen only, they do not change the output buffer)
// You can use error_reporting(0) as well, it still works as expected.
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

// Force PHP trigger an E_NOTICE
// the error handler installed above will kick in and mess the output
unset($astring);




// The innocent block of code
ob_start();
echo $astring;
$astring = ob_get_clean();



// Check the results
echo("================\n");
echo('The content of variable $astring is: [[['.$astring."]]]\n");
```

Comment: Well, after the variable $astring has been unset, it is not a string any more. It is just a non defined variable. The question asks about a string. This is an important aspect of the question. I want to know if the block of code (the three lines) defines a reliable channel for a string.

Comment: If you are sure `$astring` is a string before `ob_start()` and you only `echo()` it before `ob_get_clean()` I think you will always get it back. But if you do something like passing it to a function that does more complex processing there is always a chance that something will go wrong and you will get something else back. Is there any good reason you do this trick? I mean, since you already have your text in `$astring` why would you do this?

Comment: Without any external intervention, no custom error handler, no nothing, if `$astring` is an `Array` after you do this trick you will get the string `'Array'` instead. And that is not equal with the previous content of `$astring` by any mean.

Comment: Yes, but an array is not a string either.

Comment: If someone is willing to affirm based on his experience that in the case of a string (not null, not an array, etc.) the string will stay the same, then I will accept the answer.

Comment: If `$astring` is a string, I cannot see any reason the three lines of code you posted will change its value. I also cannot see why one would use some construct either.

Comment: In view of the update, I deselected this answer. It's true though that I personally got my answer. My issue was only that I did not realize that the output buffer is also actually a tool to reliably manage the output, pretty much as if it was an hidden PHP string. I was seeing the buffer as some unspecified intermediary stage before HTTP communication and manipulating it was some kind of unsafe hack. What I got as an answer is a metaphor that allows me to think of ob_start, etc. as standard reliable PHP tools to manage the buffer as an hidden PHP string.

Answer (score 0):

`null` is technically not a string but

```
<?php
$x=null;

ob_start();
echo $x;
$y=ob_get_clean();

var_dump($x); //NULL
var_dump($y); //string(0) ""
```

which is roughly casting `null` to string. similar results with other non string types

Comment: Since all attempts to find an exception use non strings, perhaps the answer is indeed that echoing a string in the buffer and getting it back will not change it. This is not obvious because the buffer is not originally intended to be a reliable storage device. We need to encode strings sometimes before we send them through HTTP. Some similar requirements could hold for the buffer.

Comment: The output buffer is nothing else than a hidden string variable. It is as reliable as any other string variable to hold any amount of text, limited by the `memory_limit` php.ini configuration (minus other data your script creates and the internal PHP structures for memory management) and the amount of memory available on the computer (which is virtually unlimited due to paging).

Comment: Ok, this is the answer. How do I accept it? Before, I had this vague view of the buffer, an unspecified object that was not necessarily reliable for all strings.